# No handlers could be found for logger "tldextract"

Tags: python, python-3.x

When importing extract module from tldextract, getting following log error on console. How to handle such logging in python and avoid visible on console.

> No handlers could be found for logger "tldextract"

```
from tldextract import extract

url = "https://sub.example.com/hello.html"
tsd, td, ts = extract(url)
print(td)
```

Comment: Could you please add your code? That makes it a lot easier for us to understand and possible in the first place to answer this post

Comment: What is `tldextract`? Looks like it may not have set up its logging correctly.

Comment: What is the version of your `tldextract`? The version I have -- 2.2.0 does not have this issue. `pip freeze | grep tldextract` tells the version.

Comment: @azalea I too using tldextract==2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

add this:

```py
from tldextract.tldextract import LOG
import logging
#disable tldextract stderr spam
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARN)
LOG.debug('spam spam spam')
```